# White screen on home page after migration; no errors

Tags: migration, nginx

I’m trying to migrate a site from WP Engine to an Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) LENP server and I’m getting a white screen at the root (`/`) and/or at `/index.php`. I am able to load a screen at `/wp-login.php`, but it’s not recognizing a couple of username/password pairs.

I can find no errors, anywhere, not in the nginx access or error logs and not in the the php-fpm logs. I have disabled all themes and plugins. Setting `WP_DEBUG` does nothing, but I do get output when inserting `echo` statements, e.g. in `wp-config.php`. I’ve increased `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` to 2048M. I’ve checked and double-checked file permissions.

I first tried on Wordpress.com with the same result so, to ease testing, I’m now trying on a UTM virtual machine on my Mac.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I guess WP Engine uses a random database table name prefix rather than this default in `wp-config.php`:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
```